# how to use if statment inside $.ajax( and check for string response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this simple compare inside ajax post request. I just want to check the post response for different string values but it never works. The popup function never get called even i know for sure that php response is string "mango"could you guys tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: './doit1.php',


     data: {
     title: 'test',

     },
     success: function (good)
     {
              //handle success
              if($(good) =='mango')
             {
                popitup('./doit1.php?action=stop')
                //alert(good)
             else if ($(good) =='orange')
             {
                 //do something
             }
             else
             {
                //default action
             }
      },
      failure: function (bad)
      {
          //handle any errors
          alert(bad)

      }
});


function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to wrap a jQuery wrapper around your returned data here:

```
if($(good) =='mango')
```

That is incorrect, as `good` would need to be a DOM element in that case for this to have any meaning.

If `good` is just a string value that is returned, you should just be doing this:

```
if(good == 'mango')
```

Comment: The result of `typeof good` will likely be `string`, however that depends on the server response. It could also be an `object`, but again the question does not specify what the server will return on './doit1.php' request.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping good in jQuery when it should just be put in as a string.

Replace the success function with.

```
success: function (good){
  //handle success
  if(good==="mango"){
    popitup('./doit1.php?action=stop')
  }else if(good==="orange"){
    //Do something
  }else{
    //Default Action
  }
}
```

Comment: dolondro for me "elseif" didnt work when i changed it to "else if" it worked !the other part good == 'mango' worked!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `good` is it's hard to say.  However, `$()` *always* returns a jQuery collection object that is no good for comparisons of any kind.  You probably just want to use `good == 'mango'` or a `switch`.  Perhaps it's `good.fruit == 'mango'`.